# Is there a way for CORBA client to access to server IOR file?

Tags: c++, corba, orbacus

I have a cobra server running on machine A.  It writes the stringified object to /tmp/Data.ref.   I have client running on machine B.  The client needs to access the /tmp/Data.ref file.   Currently I have to ftp the Data.ref file from machine A to machine B and put it in /tmp myself.  The server does NOT use naming service.   The machines are not NFS mounted so I can't put the file where both machines can use it.  I don't like to write a script to automatic ftp the file for other reason.

I like to know if there is a way to tell the client where to read the Data.ref on the server machine A ?

Other info: I am using Orbacus, C++, linux.   I am hoping may be there is a command line option or someway to specify the complete host,file path name if it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Use the naming service. That's what it is for, to solve this bootstrap problem. Otherwise, you're asking how to get an IOR so you can contact the server to get its IOR. The question doesn't make sense. Use COSNaming. Designed about 25 years ago. Job done.

Comment: LOL.   The job is done for you may be.   And you are right the code is about that old.   I don't want to go in an start mucking with some old code to add naming service.   Hence the statement the server does NOT use naming service.

Comment: Job done by OMG actually, that long ago. I wasn't referring to the age of your code. How could I have any idea of that? But I don't see that you have any choice about it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the edit, but I'd be obliged if you'd leave my apostrophes alone and confine yourself to typos.

Comment: TAO has support  for the IORTable, that would make it possible to construct a corbaloc (see http://www.ciaranmchale.com/corba-utilities/the-corbaloc-and-corbaname-urls.html) in code, no need to transfer an IOR file at that moment